# Java executing runas command and supplying password on prompt: "Pipe is being closed error"

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I want to start/stop a service from my java program for which I am using terminal commands. The problem is that I need to start the terminal as admin for which I am using the ProcessBuilder API.

```
public void startService(String serviceName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String[] cmdArray = {"cmd.exe", "/c", 
                         "runas /savecred /profile /user:admin \"sc start " + serviceName + "\""};

    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray).start();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
    String line;        

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line); //Prints "enter the password for admin"
}
    output.write("password"); //my password
    output.newLine();
    output.flush();
    //output.wait();
    process.destroy();
  }
```

The command executes fine and it prints `Enter the password for admin` but when I supply it through the output stream of process, I get the I/O error `java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed`. I also tried to add `echo mypassword |` before the command which does not prompt for password on terminal but is prompting from java program. Any help on this is much appreciated.

EDIT- I am getting the error on `output.flush()`

Comment: Have you tried printing `stdout` and `stderr` to see the more detailed reason for the closing pipe? also, are you running 32bit or 64 bit windows? What are your heap size/max size settings at? `heap size="??"` `max-size="??"`